# mesh vertex coloring

Tags: graphics, color, mesh, finite-element-method

So I created a mesh like this:

```
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{1, 10}, {1, 10}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 1.];
```

and want to plot it, coloring the squares:

```
Show[Graphics[ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[mesh2, All,VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Red}]], mesh2["Wireframe"]]
```

What I get is this:
[image: Weirdly colored squares.]

Now what I'd like is to color my squares homogeneously, i.e. I don't want the fancy fading effect from one square to the other, all I need is simple, even colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some cheating necessary:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{1, 10}, {1, 10}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 1.];
Show[Graphics[Riffle[Flatten[Normal[ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[mesh, All]]],
                     {Red, Green}, {1, -1, 2}]], mesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image: some Christmas-y checkerboard]

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add a little explanation about what's going on? Especially with the Riffle[]...

Comment: `Normal[]` is the usual way to convert a `GraphicsComplex[]` object into a list of graphics primitives with explicit coordinates. As for the `Riffle[]` bit: ponder on the result of `Riffle[Range[7], {Red, Green}, {1, -1, 2}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Add markers to the `QuadElement` of the mesh, a list alternating `1`/`2` equal in length to the number of elements (vis `Mod[Range@Length@q, 2, 1]`):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];    
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{1, 10}, {1, 10}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 1.] /. 
   QuadElement[q_] :> QuadElement[q, Mod[Range@Length@q, 2, 1]];
```

Then we can color each of the two markers independently:

```
mesh2["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Red], FaceForm[Green]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Like [J.M.'s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) answer, it assumes that the elements come in a certain order. The order can be inspected as follows.  The following shows the order of the elements:

```
 mesh2["Wireframe"["MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]
```

[image]

The following shows the markers:

```
mesh2["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]
```

[image]

See the tutorial [Element Mesh Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html) for more on visualizing meshes.